Can I make my computer VRAM SWAP use... VRAM in a 32 bits limited environment?
Let me clarify my question, which will sound very confusing likely.
There are some 32 bits games (Total War Rome 2) that allow only limited use of VRAM. That is a big issue when you have multiple times the amount it uses. They allow one workaround : use "unlimited video memory" option, which will uses some kind of System SWAP. But I do not think that it will use the remaining VRAM first, and if that is indeed the case, I am wondering if I can make that SWAP uses... that remaining VRAM.

Video memory isn't "some kind of system swap." It's memory shared between your iGPU's physical memory and video memory. iGPU(s) are typically limited to a very specific amount of maximum memory.  Total War Rome 2 is limited to the amount of memory a 32-bit processor can use, any system memory available past that limit is effectively not useable by the process.

Can you perhaps edit your post to remove the ellipses? Ellipses (...) indicate an incomplete thought, but you've put them in the apparent middle of sentences, which is incorrect usage, but implies there is something missing in the middle of your sentence. Please fix this: give us complete thoughts, clear descriptions, concrete statements if possible.


They allow one workaround : use "unlimited video memory" option, which will uses some kind of System SWAP. But I do not think that it will use the remaining VRAM first

I expect it won't – it'll just load everything into regular RAM, copying to VRAM as needed.

I am wondering if I can make that SWAP uses... that remaining RAM.

It is technically possible to use VRAM as swap area on Linux, but it will in fact act like a swap area – not as RAM extension – which means it will have lowest priority and won't be used by your game until you run out of system RAM. Programs cannot actually use swap storage directly; it is only used by the OS to offload unused data that was pushed out by more-actively used data.
